# Making the composition space in Gmail smaller to allow Tasks to be open at same time

Tags: gmail, google-tasks

How do I make the composition space in Gmail small enough that I can still see what I'm writing with the Tasks window open?

I love Google's Tasks functionality combined with Gmail, so I always turn the Tasks on, attached to Gmail. Yes, it is nice but eats some space.

When I read the Inbox, it is okay because I can see the sender and most parts of the subject.

When I reply to an email, it is okay because the new "People" right column eats the space anyway, so Tasks does not interfere the email writing.

When I compose a new message, here comes a problem. Because the Tasks area overlaps the writing area, so I can't see what I am writing.

Can I make it the composition space smaller, so that I can see what I'm writing with Tasks on?

Answer (score 4):

If you hold the shift key down when you click "Compose" the editor opens in a new window. You can resize that to whatever you need.